# How to exclude 0 values from a list when calculating the mean

Tags: python, list, statistics, mean

I have a list of grades like this:

```
grades = [[[4.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [4.0, 3.33], [4.0, 4.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [2.33, 2.0], [3.0, 2.67], [2.67, 3.67], [2.33, 2.0]], [[3.0, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0]], [[2.33, 4.0]], [[4.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [0, 3.33], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0]], [[3.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 3.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.0, 3.33], [3.33, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.33], [4.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 3.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 3.33], [3.67, 4.0], [3.33, 3.33], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [3.33, 4.0], [3.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 3.67], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 3.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.33], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.0, 3.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.33, 4.0], [4.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.67, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 2.33], [2.0, 3.33], [2.0, 3.67], [2.0, 2.33], [3.67, 3.33], [2.0, 2.33], [3.67, 2.33], [2.33, 3.67], [3.67, 3.67], [3.33, 2.67], [3.33, 2.0], [3.67, 4.0], [2.0, 4.0], [4.0, 2.0], [3.0, 2.0], [2.33, 2.67], [4.0, 4.0], [3.0, 2.33], [3.0, 3.33], [2.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 4.0], [2.0, 2.0], [2.33, 4.0], [4.0, 2.0], [2.67, 3.33], [2.0, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0]], [[3.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [4.0, 0], [0, 3.0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [4.0, 0], [0, 4.0], [0, 3.33], [0, 3.67], [0, 3.0], [0, 4.0], [0, 3.0], [0, 3.67], [0, 3.0], [0, 3.0], [4.0, 0], [0, 3.67], [0, 3.0], [0, 3.0], [0, 4.0], [3.0, 0], [0, 3.0], [0, 3.67], [0, 3.0], [0, 3.33], [0, 4.0], [3.33, 0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [2.33, 0], [0, 2.33]], [[3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.67], [3.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.33], [4.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [3.33, 4.0], [3.0, 3.33], [4.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [2.33, 3.67], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 2.33], [3.67, 2.33], [3.0, 2.33], [3.67, 4.0], [2.33, 2.33], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 2.67], [4.0, 3.67], [2.0, 2.0], [4.0, 2.67], [2.0, 3.33], [3.0, 2.33], [2.0, 3.0], [3.67, 2.33], [3.67, 2.67], [3.33, 2.33], [2.67, 2.0], [4.0, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [2.67, 4.0], [4.0, 3.33], [2.67, 2.33], [2.0, 4.0], [3.67, 2.33], [3.0, 2.67], [2.67, 3.0], [2.67, 4.0], [3.67, 2.33], [2.0, 3.33], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.0]], [[3.67, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.67], [3.67, 3.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 4.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 4.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 3.33], [3.67, 4.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.33, 3.67], [3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [3.67, 3.67], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 3.33], [3.33, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.33, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.33], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.33], [4.0, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.33], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.67], [3.67, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.0], [3.67, 2.33], [3.67, 3.33], [3.33, 2.33], [3.33, 3.67], [3.67, 2.0], [3.0, 3.33]], [[4.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.33, 0], [2.0, 0]], [[4.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.33, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.33, 4.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 3.67], [4.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.0, 3.0], [3.33, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.33], [3.33, 4.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 4.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.33], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 3.33], [4.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.33], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.33], [4.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 3.67], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 3.0], [3.33, 3.67], [4.0, 3.67], [3.67, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.67, 2.67], [3.67, 2.0], [3.0, 2.0], [2.33, 3.33], [3.0, 2.0], [3.0, 2.0], [4.0, 2.0], [2.67, 2.0], [4.0, 4.0], [2.67, 2.33], [2.33, 3.0], [4.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.0], [2.67, 3.0], [2.33, 3.67], [2.0, 3.33], [2.67, 3.67], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [4.0, 3.33], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 2.33], [2.67, 2.0], [2.33, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0], [2.0, 2.0], [4.0, 2.33], [2.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.67], [2.67, 3.33], [2.67, 3.0], [3.33, 4.0], [2.33, 3.67], [3.67, 3.33], [2.33, 3.67], [2.0, 3.33], [2.0, 3.33], [2.67, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 2.0], [3.0, 2.33], [2.33, 2.33], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.33]], [[3.33, 3.67]], [[3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0]], [[4.0, 4.0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [3.67, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 4.0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 3.33], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [3.67, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 3.67], [0, 0]], [[4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 4.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.67], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.33], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.33, 3.33], [4.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.33, 4.0], [3.0, 3.33], [4.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.33], [4.0, 3.33], [4.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.67], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.67], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 4.0], [2.0, 4.0], [3.33, 2.67], [2.33, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 2.67], [3.33, 3.67], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 3.67], [2.67, 3.67], [2.0, 2.33], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 3.33], [2.33, 3.0], [3.33, 2.33], [3.67, 3.0], [2.33, 3.0], [2.33, 3.67], [3.67, 3.0], [2.33, 2.33], [2.67, 4.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 2.67], [2.67, 2.33], [3.33, 3.33], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.33], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 2.0], [3.67, 2.33], [2.67, 2.0]], [[3.0, 0], [0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [0, 3.67], [0, 3.0], [0, 3.67], [0, 3.0], [0, 4.0], [0, 3.33], [0, 3.67], [0, 3.33], [0, 3.33], [0, 3.67], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [0, 3.0], [0, 3.33], [3.67, 0], [3.0, 0], [0, 3.33], [0, 3.33], [0, 3.67], [0, 4.0], [0, 4.0], [0, 4.0], [0, 3.67], [0, 4.0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [3.33, 0], [0, 3.0], [3.0, 0], [2.0, 0], [0, 3.67], [0, 3.67], [0, 3.33], [0, 2.0], [0, 3.33], [0, 3.0], [2.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [0, 2.0], [0, 2.0], [3.33, 3.67], [2.33, 0], [0, 4.0], [0, 2.33], [2.33, 0], [2.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [3.67, 0], [2.0, 0], [2.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.0, 0], [2.33, 0], [2.67, 0], [3.0, 0], [2.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [2.33, 0], [3.33, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.67, 0], [4.0, 0], [2.33, 0], [3.0, 0], [2.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [2.33, 0], [3.33, 0], [2.0, 0], [2.33, 0], [2.33, 0], [2.33, 0], [2.67, 0], [2.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [3.33, 0], [2.33, 0], [3.67, 0], [4.0, 0], [4.0, 0], [2.67, 0], [3.0, 0], [2.0, 0], [2.67, 0]], [[3.33, 3.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0]], [[3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.67], [3.67, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 3.0], [3.33, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 3.67], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 3.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 4.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.33], [4.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.67, 4.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.67], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.67], [4.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.33], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 4.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.0], [3.67, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 2.67], [3.67, 2.33], [3.0, 2.0], [3.33, 3.33], [2.0, 2.33], [3.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.67], [2.0, 4.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.67, 2.33], [2.0, 2.67], [4.0, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [2.33, 4.0], [2.67, 2.67], [2.67, 2.67], [3.67, 4.0], [2.33, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [2.33, 2.33], [3.0, 2.67], [3.0, 3.0], [3.33, 2.0], [2.33, 3.33], [3.67, 2.0], [2.33, 3.0], [2.0, 2.67], [2.33, 4.0], [2.67, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.67], [2.0, 4.0], [3.0, 2.0], [2.67, 4.0], [3.67, 2.67], [2.67, 2.67], [2.33, 3.67], [3.0, 2.0], [3.67, 4.0], [2.33, 4.0], [2.0, 3.67], [2.0, 4.0], [3.33, 4.0], [4.0, 2.67], [2.33, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.67, 2.33], [2.33, 3.33], [4.0, 2.33], [2.67, 2.67], [3.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67]], [[3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.33], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.67], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.33], [4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.33, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.33], [4.0, 4.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.33], [3.33, 3.67], [3.67, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [3.0, 3.33], [4.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.33, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.67, 3.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [4.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.33, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [3.33, 3.33], [3.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.67], [3.33, 4.0], [3.67, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.0, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 4.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.67], [3.33, 3.0], [3.0, 3.33], [4.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.67], [4.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [3.0, 3.67], [4.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.0], [3.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.0], [4.0, 3.67], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.0, 3.67], [3.67, 3.33], [3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.67], [3.33, 3.33], [4.0, 3.0], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [4.0, 3.33], [3.67, 3.33], [3.33, 3.33], [3.33, 3.0], [2.33, 3.33], [2.67, 2.67], [3.33, 3.67], [2.0, 3.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [3.33, 4.0], [4.0, 3.67], [2.67, 2.67], [4.0, 4.0], [3.33, 3.67], [2.67, 3.0], [3.33, 3.67], [2.67, 3.33], [3.33, 3.0], [4.0, 3.0], [2.0, 4.0], [4.0, 3.67], [2.0, 2.67], [4.0, 3.67], [2.0, 2.0], [3.67, 3.33], [4.0, 4.0], [2.0, 2.33], [3.67, 2.67], [2.33, 2.33], [3.0, 3.0], [3.33, 2.67], [4.0, 2.67], [2.0, 2.33], [3.0, 4.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.33, 2.33], [2.67, 2.67], [2.67, 2.67], [2.0, 2.0], [3.67, 3.67], [3.0, 4.0], [2.67, 3.67], [3.0, 2.33]]]
```

and I want to find the mean of each sublist. For that reason I did this:

```
gpa = [[mean(sub_list) for sub_list in list] for list in grades]
```

But the problem is that some sublists have the value 0.0 and of course the code takes it under consideration. Is there a way for me to ignore those 0.0 when they appear and calculate the mean based on the rest of the values? Based on this list, I only have 2 values per sublist, but there are others that have 4 and 5 elements inside them. It is just crucial for the thing I am calculating that is why I need those 0 not to be considered at all.

I am using **statistics mean**

Comment: Can I use numpy?

Comment: I did it with numpy but because I have a lot of lists in my program, I faced issues comparing them and for that reason I turned back to statistics! @GilseungAhn

Comment: don't bring a gun to a knife fight, bro.

Comment: Can you do `mean([i for i in sub_list if i!=0] or [0])` ?

Comment: do you mean based on my code to do [[mean(sub_list) for sub_list in list if i!=0 or [0]]] ? @AndrejKesely or you mean something else?Sorry I got confused

Comment: @piggy Yes, I meant your code: `gpa = [[mean([i for i in sub_list if i!=0] or [0]) for sub_list in list] for list in grades]`

Comment: "But the problem is that some sublists have the value 0.0 and of course the code takes it under consideration." *Why shouldn't it*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel because these 0 values are representing empty strings from another list that are supposed to be grades of courses. I just gave them the value 0 in order not to be empty strings in this list because I couldn't calculate the mean like that and if I give them the value nan I get too many results of mean as nan which I do not understand why, since the standard deviation is a number. I do not know if my answer made it clear

Comment: @AndrejKesely your code worked! It is exactly what I needed ! I dont know if you would like to provide it as an answer so I accept it as the one I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: @piggy Ok, I write an answer.

Comment: Did you consider, in these cases, just not putting a value into the list at all?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes of course I had them empty at the beginning and there would be errors when I would try to calculate different stuff that is why I needed to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your input list `grades`, there are sublists where all values are equal to zero. If you filter all zeros, the `mean` function will throw an error.

One solution is to provide default value of zero if all values were filtered out.

For example:

```
gpa = [[mean([i for i in sub_list if i!=0] or [0]) for sub_list in list] for list in grades]
print(gpa)
```

Prints:

```
[[3.5, 3.0, 3.5, 3.33, 3.0, 3.835, 3.335, 3.5, 3.665, 3.665, 3.0, 3.67, 3.165, 3.5, 3.335, 3.665, 3.665, 4.0, 3.335, ...

... and so on (without throwing an error)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you again! @AndrejKesely

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your mean cannot be affected by a zero value.

Secondly, if you are ignoring zeros, then, will you be reducing the divisor in mean's formula i.e. (mean = sum(x) / (n - no_of_zeros).

If you are requiring the second thing, then, use `your_list.count(0)` and subtract it from the length of list i.e. `len(your_list)`.

In this way, you can really ignore the zeros.

Comment: how you mean it cannot be affected? It is just that the 0 values mean empty string in another list I have so I need to exclude them since it is different to have 4+0/2 = 2 than 4/1 = 4 @AbhishekVerma

Comment: Read what I wrote after secondly, bro. You want the second approach. I have written the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use numpy, try this code.
It is simple and fast.
I replace zero as `np.nan`, and use `nanmean` which returns mean of values except for `np.nan`.

```
import numpy as np
grades = np.array(grades)
grades[grades == 0] = np.nan
np.nanmean(grades, axis = 1)
```

Comment: OP's example list isn't compatible with a single rectangular array, so the naive numpy approach probably won't work.